# Language not change in action bar in android

Tags: android, localization

I want to change the language the language from english to arabic.If i select arabic means all text should changed.But the text in action bar and navigation drawer not changed.What to do for changing the language in action bar and navigation drawer.I have tried some thing like this.`

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                switch (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) {

                    case 0:
                        changeLocale(Emp_LocalizationActivity.this,"en");

                        break;
                    case 1:

                        changeLocale(Emp_LocalizationActivity.this,"ar");

                        break;

                    default:
                        config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                        break;


                }
                Intent i= new Intent(Emp_LocalizationActivity.this,Emp_Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

   public static void changeLocale(Activity activity, String language)
    {
        final Resources res = activity.getResources();
        final Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (language == null || language.length() == 0)
        {
            conf.locale = Locale.getDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            final int idx = language.indexOf('-');
            if (idx != -1)
            {
                final String[] split = language.split("-");
                conf.locale = new Locale(split[0], split[1].substring(1));
            }
            else
            {
                conf.locale = new Locale(language);
            }
        }

        res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);
    }
```

`